# Memoization, Interpreters, and Closures

Tags: programming-languages, scheme, interpreter, memoization

So I'm experimenting, and have a programming language created in scheme. I've built an interpreter for it as well, which is most of the code below.

I'd like to rewrite the interpreter so that it builds closures with smaller environments, ie. when building a closure, it uses an environment that is like the current environment but only holds variables that are free variables in the function part of the closure. I'm learning memoization, but this is confusing.

EDIT: I'm now using a racket equivalent of this, so if it's easier there, you should give me suggestions.

```
(define-struct var (string)) ;; a variable, e.g., (make-var "foo")
(define-struct int (num)) ;; a constant number, e.g., (make-int 17)
(define-struct add (e1 e2)) ;; add two expressions
(define-struct fun (name formal body)) ;; a recursive 1-argument function
(define-struct closure (fun env)) ;; closures (made at run-time)

(define (envlookup env str)
    (cond [(null? env) (error "unbound variable during evaluation" str)]
        [(equal? (caar env) str) (cdar env)]
        [#t (envlookup (cdr env) str)]))

(define (eval-prog p)
    (letrec
        ([f (lambda (env p)
            (cond [(var? p) (envlookup env (var-string p))]
                    [(int? p) p]
                    [(add? p) (let ([v1 (f env (add-e1 p))]
                                    [v2 (f env (add-e2 p))])
                                        (if (and (int? v1) (int? v2))
                                            (make-int (+ (int-num v1) (int-num v2)))
                                            (error "TTPL addition applied to non-number")))]
                    [(fun? p) (make-closure p env)]
                    [(closure? p) p]
                    [#t (error "bad TTPL expression")]))])
    (f () p)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First question: do you have mutation of bindings in your language? It looks like you don't, currently, but perhaps you're planning to add it. If you do, then copying bindings opens up a new can of worms; additional indirection is required.

Answer to your question: yes, you can certainly do this, and most language implementations do. This is related to the property of being "safe-for-space", whereby closures avoid retaining references to large values that could otherwise be collected.

Implementing this is pretty straightforward: you probably want to annotate every expression with its free variables, by making a single static pass over the program. In Racket, I would probably build a hash table that associates expressions with a list of their free variables.

For what it's worth, I can imagine about seven ways in which you could accidentally make your language quite a bit slower by doing this :).

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want to create something like flat closures, or what Dybvig called "display closures". That is, you have to recursively find free variables in your lambda, and then create a representation of the closure containing just those free variables.

For example,

```
((lambda (x) (lambda (f) (f x))) a)
```

would create a closure that looks like `[code, a]`.

Take a look at Dybvig's [Three Implementation Models for Scheme](http://www.cs.indiana.edu/~dyb/pubs/3imp.pdf), page 88.

Answer (score 1):

If you don’t mind reading some Haskell, [Write Yourself a Scheme in 48 Hours](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Write_Yourself_a_Scheme_in_48_Hours/Defining_Scheme_Functions) demonstrates how closures are created: when a `(lambda ...)` expression is encountered, its closure is simply set to the current environment (a list of bindings from names to values). When a lambda is evaluated, its body is evaluated in the context of that closure plus the argument bindings—not, of course, the current environment.

It sounds like what you want to do is cull the environment that becomes the closure, perhaps for the sake of efficiency. To do this, you could search the function for names, and keep only those that don’t appear in the argument list. However, this may be excessive, as *every* name the lambda uses—except for its arguments—will need to appear in the closure. As such, I suggest simply referring to the environment that you already have, most of which will be shared anyway.